# Ubuntu 22.10, Unknown kernel command line parameters

Tags: grub2, kernel, 22.10

Ubuntu 22.10 Desktop

**Seeing these messages in /var/log/syslog...**

```
Mar  6 09:09:09 al-Inspiron-7700-AIO kernel: [    0.062877] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-35-generic root=UUID=f0db2226-e28d-46dd-9b5a-457c87987ed2 ro quiet splash systemd.restore_state=0 acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi=Linux vt.handoff=7

Mar  6 09:09:09 al-Inspiron-7700-AIO kernel: [    0.062945] Unknown kernel command line parameters "splash BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-35-generic", will be passed to user space.
```

**Here's my /etc/default/grub...**

```
    GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
    GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
    GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
    GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
    GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
    
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash systemd.restore_state=0 acpi_backlight=
    vendor acpi_osi=Linux"
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

I've tried (even) commenting out the last two lines, and I still get the error message.

**This is in /boot/grub/grub.cfg...**

```
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-35-generic root=UUID=f0db2226-e28d-46dd-9b5a-457c87987ed2 ro  quiet splash systemd.restore_state=0 acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi=Linux $vt_handoff
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-35-generic root=UUID=f0db2226-e28d-46dd-9b5a-457c87987ed2 ro recovery nomodeset dis_ucode_ldr
```

Any ideas where this error is coming from?

Comment: I don't think it's an error exactly - just an informational message telling you that those parameters are ignored by the kernel and hence passed to `init` (i.e. `systemd`). See somewhat related [Systemd invocation parameters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/333297/systemd-invocation-parameters)